# I got no feedback for GoogleAPI OAuth Developer Verficication request since more than 15 days. How can I contact verification team?

Tags: oauth, google-api, verification

During verification process Google requested some changes, a video in which to present my application and details about why I need to use some sensitive scopes (like google.drive or spreadsheets). I sent all the details but still no reply. I have no idea if the application is still under verification or the whole process was abandoned all together.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack overflow is not Google support we cant help you with application verification we suggest you contact Google.

Comment: That being said when did you send in the video?  Verification process is not fast it can take weeks and sometimes months to get verified.